# Why if the metric tensor components are constant then SR applies?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

In [this paper](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_GRelativity_1916.pdf), at the end of page 177, it says that if the metric tensor components $g_{\mu \nu}$ are constant, then

> with a suitable choice of the system of reference, the special theory of relativity holds good for a finite region of the continuum.

But the metric tensor components being constant doesn't mean it is Minkowski (which is what I understand by "SR applies"). The metric is diagonalizable because it is symmetric, but not necessarily with eigenvalues $(-1, -1, -1, 1)$. Why does he say so then?

Comment: Has the author specialized to the case of Lorentzian manifolds?

Comment: If we are doing GR, then I think diagonalizing the metric will give the metric tensor for SR. But we are not on some general manifold otherwise I think your worry is valid.

Comment: If the eigenvalues are not unity then you can simply make them so by changing the coordinates with $$x^\mu \to \frac {1}{\sqrt{g_{\mu\mu}}} x^\mu$$

Comment: Why if we are in GR diagonalizing the metric will give SR @Amara ?

Comment: @MiguelBolín , my reasoning is purely physical, if I am doing GR, and I make my coordinate patch small enough then I should not see any curvature and this is the regime of SR. So no matter how complicated my metric tensor looks like in my small coordinate patch there should some coordinate transformation that produces the metric tensor of SR. Again I am assuming we are doing something physical in GR and not just  some very general metric. i.e I am putting in the physics so that I get the limit I want. Einstein's equations tell us dynamics but we have to choose initial and boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The metric is diagonalizable, yes, and then with further coordinate transformations it can be converted to Minkowski; see, for example, Schutz exercise 6.3 where he guides you through the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize some ideas in the comments and the other answer and add an important point regarding frames that I think is interesting to keep in mind.

In Lorentzian signature, if you go to an orthonormal frame $\{e_a\}$ you will always get the components $g_{ab}=\text{diag}(-1,-1,-1,+1)$ (or with opposite signs depending on conventions). Take an arbitrary point of the spacetime and an arbitrary coordinate chart with associated basis $\{\partial/\partial x^\mu\}$. The orthonormal frame I mention above can always be found, and is what we choose in the Vielbein formulation for example. In general it will have the form $e_a = e^\mu{}_a \partial/\partial x^\mu$, where $e^\mu{}_a (x)$ is just the change of basis matrix, which depends on the point.

That the metric can be diagonalized in a certain frame does not imply that you are in Minkowski space, obviously. The point is that such an orthonormal frame does not need to be a coordinate frame. Only if you find coordinates $y^a(x)$ such that $e^\mu{}_a = \partial x^\mu /\partial y^a$, i.e., such that the orthonormal frame $\{e_a\}$ is the basis associated to those new coordinates, THEN you are in Minkowski space.

I just want to clarify with my answer that the work "system of reference" is ambiguous (if no more context is given, maybe it was defined before in that text). If by a system of reference you mean a set of coordinates, then everything is fine. But if you mean a (smooth) basis covering your surroundings (the open set of a given chart), it is not necessarily true because such a basis always exists.